# .NET Configuration / ConfigurationManager exePath

Tags: c#, .net, configuration

When creating a Configuration object, it asks for a path to a config file... I keep getting an exception thrown for an invalid file path... What's a valid path? I've tried "config.config" and ".\config.config", but I can't think of anything else.

Comment: Please show the code you're talking about. Also, `ConfigurationManager` has nothing to do with the C# programming language. It has to do with the .NET Framework. The exact same problem would exist if you were using F# or VB.NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is for accessing your app.config file, you can use `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` static class, i.e.

```
var setting = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MySetting"];
```

**Edit:** You probably want something like this then:

```
var configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None); // choose ConfigurationUserLevel value, or provide @"c:\path\to\some\exe\"
configuration.AppSettings.Settings.Add("test", "value"); // for new configs
configuration.AppSettings.Settings["test2"].Value = "somevalue"; // for modification of existing keys
c.Save(); // or choose save location
```

Comment: It's not, because I want to set the settings as well as reading from them.

Comment: Updated answer - hopefully that helps

Answer (score 0):

The path would be in the `Environment.CurrentDirectory` where the .EXE is residing in. If I am not mistaken, the app.config file when added to the project, and when the project gets built, it will generate an config file in the same place as where the .EXE was compiled to, usually `bin\debug` or `bin\release`, for an example, suppose the application name was `foo.exe`, its related config file would be `foo.exe.config`.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.